# User uploading images to specific directories

Tags: php, image, upload, user-accounts

So basically I have a site in which certain members are allowed to upload images (comic pages) to their own image galleries (to a specific comic). I have a successful image uploading script that I used to upload profile/avatar images for each member, but now that I want to upload files to a more specific place I'm having a little trouble.

Here's what I have so far:

(This is what appears at the top of the page)

```
<?php
session_start();
$toplinks = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // Put stored session variables into local php variable
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $toplinks = '<a href="member_profile.php?id=' . $userid . '">' . $username . '</a> &bull; 
    <a href="member_account.php">Account</a> &bull; 
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
} else {
    $toplinks = '<a href="join_form.php">Register</a> &bull; <a href="login.php">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

(This is the uploading script)

```
<?php
// Here we run a login check
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
   echo 'Please <a href="login.php">log in</a> to access your account';
  exit(); 
} 
// Place Session variable 'id' into local variable
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
// Process the form if it is submitted
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] != "") {
    // Run error handling on the file
    // Set Max file size limit to somewhere around 120kb
    $maxfilesize = 400000;
    // Check file size, if too large exit and tell them why
    if($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] > $maxfilesize ) { 
        echo "<br /><br />Your image was too large. Must be 400kb or less, please<br /><br />
        <a href=\"upload_comic.php\">click here</a> to try again";
        unlink($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']); 
        exit();
    // Check file extension to see if it is .jpg or .gif, if not exit and tell them why
    } else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ) ) {
        echo "<br /><br />Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png and it must be one of those three formats.<br />
        <a href=\"upload_comic.php\">click here</a> to try again";
        unlink($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
        exit();
        // If no errors on the file process it and upload to server 
    } else { 
        // Rename the pic
        $newname = ""; //numbers only, so they show up sequentially
        // Set the direntory for where to upload it, use the member id to hit their folder 
        // Upload the file
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], "comics/$comicid/".$newname)) {
            echo "Success, the image has been uploaded and will display to visitors!<br /><br />
            <a href=\"member_account.php\">Click here</a> to return to your profile edit area";
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again. If it continually fails, contact us by email. <br /><br />
            <a href=\"member_account.php\">Click here</a> to return to your profile edit area";
            exit();
        }
    } // close else after file error checks
} // close if post the form
?>
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to upload an image like this: **comics/comic_id/chapter_id/uploaded_file.extension**

With the user profile image uploader, I was able to grab the $ID from the $_Session['id'] variable, but with the comics, I don't really know how to grab that information and use it to set the comic_id directory (chapter_id will be selected on the form so I'm not too worried about that one).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I presume you want to see how many sequentially numbered files are in their folder, give it the next id in sequence? You should also give them the option to overwrite an existing file, no?

Comment: Yes. I'm not too worried about that part though, I'm more concerned with getting my directory paths in order. It's probably not difficult to do, I just don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a file to wherever you choose. This will save the comic in a folder of its id and chapter, but retaining the filename. If you wanted to use the comic id as the filename I am sure you can work that out.

```
$basepath = "/home/path/to/www/comics/member_" . $member_id . "/";

function construct_path($chapter_id,$comic_id) 
{
   $saveimagepath = $basepath . $comic_id . $chapter
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
   echo 'Please <a href="login.php">log in</a> to access your account';
  exit(); 
} 
// Place Session variable 'id' into local variable
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
// Process the form if it is submitted
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] != "") {
    // Run error handling on the file
    // Set Max file size limit to somewhere around 120kb
    $maxfilesize = 400000;
    // Check file size, if too large exit and tell them why
    if($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] > $maxfilesize ) { 
        echo "<br /><br />Your image was too large. Must be 400kb or less, please<br /><br />
        <a href=\"upload_comic.php\">click here</a> to try again";
        unlink($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']); 
        exit();
    // Check file extension to see if it is .jpg or .gif, if not exit and tell them why
    } else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ) ) {
        echo "<br /><br />Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png and it must be one of those three formats.<br />
        <a href=\"upload_comic.php\">click here</a> to try again";
        unlink($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
        exit();
        // If no errors on the file process it and upload to server 
    } else { 
        // Rename the pic
        $newname = $saveimagepath . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']; 
//numbers only, so they show up sequentially
        // Set the direntory for where to upload it, use the member id to hit their folder 
        // Upload the file
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $newname)) {
            echo "Success, the image has been uploaded and will display to visitors!<br /><br />
            <a href=\"member_account.php\">Click here</a> to return to your profile edit area";
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again. If it continually fails, contact us by email. <br /><br />
            <a href=\"member_account.php\">Click here</a> to return to your profile edit area";
            exit();
        }
    } // close else after file error checks
} // close if post the form
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $_SESSION variable is available at any site you started with session_start(). So if the id is set right after the login, you can access this value at any other page in the same way with $_SESSION['id']. Make sure that the value of id won't kill your filesystem or leads to security issues!

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds ignorant (conceptualizing php is hard for me). If I call $_Session['id'] from a list of comics (identified by their id #'s), would it set the $_SESSION['id'] to the comic id? And if I've already used $_SESSION['id'] to catch a user id, will that pose a problem?  I added some more PHP to my post that I call at the beginning of the page to check for login. Thanks!